# How to properly derive/inherit from a QGraphicsLineItem?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to create a custom `QGraphicsLineItem` called Edge, but I'm not doing it well I'm new in `Qt`.
For now, I can't for example do `scene->add(edgeItem)` without error  no viable conversion from '`Edge`' to '`QGraphicsItem` *'.

My edge.h

```
#ifndef EDGE_H
#define EDGE_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>


class Edge:public QGraphicsLineItem
{
private:
    QGraphicsEllipseItem * state1;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem * state2;

public:
    enum { Type = UserType + 2 };
    int type() const override;
    Edge(QGraphicsEllipseItem * s1, QGraphicsEllipseItem* s2);

    QGraphicsEllipseItem *getState1() const;
    void setState1(QGraphicsEllipseItem *value);
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *getState2() const;
    void setState2(QGraphicsEllipseItem *value);


     QList<QPointF> centerPoints();

};

#endif // EDGE_H
```

My edge.cpp

```
#include "edge.h"
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>

Edge::Edge(QGraphicsEllipseItem* s1, QGraphicsEllipseItem* s2)
{
    setState1(s1);
    setState2(s2);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsScenePositionChanges);
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

}

int Edge::type() const
{
    return Type;
}

QGraphicsEllipseItem *Edge::getState1() const
{
    return state1;
}

void Edge::setState1(QGraphicsEllipseItem *value)
{
    state1 = value;
}

QGraphicsEllipseItem *Edge::getState2() const
{
    return state2;
}

void Edge::setState2(QGraphicsEllipseItem *value)
{
    state2 = value;
}



QList<QPointF> Edge::centerPoints()
{

            QPointF point1(state1->rect().x() + state1->rect().width()/2,state1->rect().y()+ state1-> rect().height()/2);
            QPointF point2(state2->rect().x()+state2->rect().width()/2,state2->rect().y()+ state2-> rect().height()/2);

            QList<QPointF> list;
            list.append(point1);
            list.append(point2);

            return list;

}
```

Can someone show me how I can modify my Edge to make it a "real" `QGraphicsItem` ?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].  From the error message `"no viable conversion from Edge to QGraphicsItem *"` it would appear -- since `Edge` *does* inherit from `QGraphicsItem` -- that you are passing an `Edge` where you should be passing an `Edge *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example of proper inheritance

so `.h`

```
 class Edge: public QGraphicsLineItem
    {
    public:
        Edge(QGraphicsEllipseItem * s1 = nullptr, QGraphicsEllipseItem* s2= nullptr, QGraphicsItem* parent = nullptr);
        //.....
    
    };
```

and `.cpp`

```
Edge::Edge(QGraphicsEllipseItem * s1, QGraphicsEllipseItem* s2, QGraphicsItem* parent) 
    :QGraphicsLineItem( parent)
{
 //.........
}
```

Comment: One more thing : how can I get the functions from QGraphicsLineItem like setLine() ? I want to use it as a classic QGraphicsLineItem and draw the actual line

Comment: Since you have derived from `public QGraphicsLineItem` and `QGraphicsLineItem::setLine(...)` exists, you should be able to call `edge->setLine(...)` on a variable declared like `Edge* edge = new Edge(...);`. Is this not the case? You don't have to implement the methods of your parent class, if you want to use it in the exact same way.

Answer (score 0):

When creating your Edge class instance, do it this way.

```
Edge* someinstance = new Edge(); 
scene->addItem(someinstance);
```

I assume what you're doing is.

```
Edge instance;
scene->addItem(instance);
```

So compiler tries implicitly convert Edge object to QGraphicsItem* object wich is impossible.

Comment: what I was doing was `Edge instance(item1,item2)`. Is there is a difference between `Edge* someinstance = new Edge();`  and `Edge* someinstance();` ?

Comment: In this `Edge* someinstance = new Edge();` you can operate with your object you've created with someinstance pointer. With other example `codeEdge* someinstance();`  i don't know what you are trying to do but it seems nonsense to me as a c++ syntax.

Comment: For reducing issues like this try using some IDE or take a look at compile errors of your compiler.